# Parse Query: order by elements in another Array

Tags: swift, uitableview, caching, parse-platform

Ok I am so close to figuring this out. I have usernames in usernames array. I am trying to do a query where I order the results based off of the sequence in usernames array. I tried using a NSSortDescriptor, but I do not think that it accomplishes this. Thanks

```
func photoQuery () {
    let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "usernameArray", ascending: false)
    let photoQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserPhoto")
    photoQuery.whereKey("username", containedIn: usernameArray)
    photoQuery.order(by: descriptor)
    photoQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                if error == nil {
                    let userImageFile = object["photo"] as? PFFileObject
                    let urlString = userImageFile?.url as! String
                    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                        if let imageData = data {
                            self.urlArray.append(urlString as NSString)
                            self.cache.setObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!, forKey: urlString as NSString)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your schema? I mean.. what are the fields/types that you have in the UserPhoto class? Also.. what do you mean by "order the results based off of the sequence in usernames array"? Can you give an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, the userPhoto class contains each user's profile picture. Based off of the specific sequence listed in the username array... ex: Johnny, Sam, Andrew... I want to display the profile image associated with each one in the same sequence. Johnny's picture, Sam's picture, Andrew's picture. Right now, the method looksup all photos matching all three criteria but decides in whatever way it wants which photos to match to the usernames.

Comment: I am afraid it will not be possible to be done. You can either do multiple queries (one for each element of the array), or order by username, or order in the client side.

Comment: So going forward you're saying I need to run say 10 queries for 10 different users. That will surely hurt battery life and take a long time. Is there not another way?

Comment: If we are talking about 10 different users, I'd order in the client side.